# How can I create a fixed text region within image size in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Basically I've an image with text inside it as seen in the image below:

[contained_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A66KB.png)

But when I resize the window, the text "falls out" of the screen:

[uncontained_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYPtl.png)

This is the HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <img class="cpu" src="images/cpu.png" alt="cpu-img">
    <div class="text">
      <!-- text here -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.container {
position: relative;
padding-top: 100px;
background-color: #222831;
color: #EEEEEE;
}

.cpu {
width: 21%;
padding-top: 40px;
}

.text {
position: absolute;
top: 46.5%;
left: 40%;
width: 20%;
word-break: break-word;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue so text doesn't fall out of screen image?

Answer (score 0):

When you resize your screen, the size of your text inside the `<img>` tag needs to be changed, so you have to change the size of the text container as well or hide the overflow texts by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `.text` element.

Comment: If it wont work, please attach your cpu.png so we check where the problem is

Comment: I tried over-flow:hidden on .text and it didnt fix the problem, here is the image: https://imgur.com/a/0ju7aXM

Comment: @AdryanZeigler there was a typo on the answer, could you try adding `overflow: hidden` instead?

Comment: He needs the text to align in a PNG Photo. But the problem is that whenever he you change the screen size, the photo mesurements changes and the text is not aligned anymore. I beleive he can youse @mediaquery to change the text size when the screen size changes